# no module named gtk

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, homebrew

Why I install gtk & pygtk with homebrew, but python still not able to find it:

```
brew test -v pygtk
Testing pygtk
==> chmod +x test.py
chmod +x test.py 
==> ./test.py
./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygtk
ImportError: No module named pygtk
Error: pygtk: failed
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the module is in your python path. Check where you have installed the package and Add this in your bashrc,

```
#.bashrc        
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/opt/lib/python2.4/site-packages/psycopg2/:path_to_module
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2):

The libraries are not in the PYTHONPATH.  I'd try:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```